# graph-tool - Edges between separate graphs?

Tags: graph-tool

In `graph-tool`, I have a forest of graphs and I want to add special edges across the graphs from/to specific nodes without encapsulating all the graphs into a new bigger multi-graph. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as it would invalidate the definition of a graph. You can, however, merge graphs together with `graph_union()`, and connect their vertices with edges. If necessary, you can differentiate the types of edges with property maps.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, and thanks for the awesome framework! However, I see this as a design decision rather than a violation of graph definitions. For instance, the framework could automatically do a graph union when cross-graph edges are added without invalidating either graphs. Maybe take this as a feature request :-).